# delete in threads gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

This program counts the occurrence of a word in a line. It runs as expected, but I have 2 concerns:

1. `delete tmp` is commented as of now (line 57). If it is uncommented and compiled, my executable gives "segmentation fault". Oddly, it doesn't crash while running in `gdb` nor with `valgrind`.
2. Lines 65 and 66: ideally these threads would need to be joined. But, I am getting correct output even though they are not joined. Is this how it behaves for a shared (volatile) variable?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>
#define MAX_BUFF 1000

using namespace std;
volatile int tcount=0;
pthread_mutex_t myMux;

typedef struct data
{
    string line;
    string arg;
}tdata;

void *calcWordCount(void *arg)
{
    tdata *tmp = (tdata *)arg;
    string line = tmp->line;
    string s = tmp->arg;
    int startpos = 0;
    int finds = 0;
    while ((startpos = line.find(s, startpos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
            ++finds;
            startpos+=1;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&myMux);
            tcount++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMux);
    }
    //cout<<endl<<line<<s<<" "<<finds<<endl;
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t thread_ids[10000];
  int cnt=1;
  int thread_cnt=0;
  void *exit_status;
  int targc=argc;
  ifstream infile("testfile");  
  string line;
  while(getline(infile,line))
  {
        while(targc >1)
        {
              tdata *tmp = new tdata;
          tmp->line = line;
              tmp->arg = argv[cnt];
              pthread_create(&thread_ids[thread_cnt],NULL,calcWordCount,tmp);
              thread_cnt++;
              cnt++;
              targc--;
              //delete tmp;
        }
    cnt=1;
    targc=argc;

}
infile.close();
int j;
/*for(j=0;j<thread_cnt;j++)
    pthread_join(thread_ids[j],&exit_status);*/
cout<<tcount<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't delete `tmp` because the thread you just created is still running.

Comment: You'll need to keep the `tmp` data pointers until you have joined all of your threads.

Comment: but then, how will I keep track of those to free them later ? There may be multiple such structures allocated.

Comment: @Ajit _'how will I keep track'_ You may use a `std::vector<tdata*>` for instance.

Comment: @ ^, Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this. Also, Bathsheba has suggested to use shared_ptr let me see if it works.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `volatile` is not sufficient to make `tcount` thread safe. Consider using `std::atomic<int> tcount` instead.

Comment: @nwp I didn't knew it...thanks for the info. btw, I got the volatile info from this link http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/unix/Mutex.htm

Comment: @Ajit The `volatile` is useless in your example. As a rule of thumb [never use `volatile` in combination with threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading). It will break your code in very interesting ways. Also there is [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) and [std::async](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/) to make your life much easier.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ , I have implemented the vector<tdata*> ptrs solution  and using for(j=0;j<ptrs.size();j++) delete ptrs[j]; to free those. Although it seems to be correct, will this solution be accepted as a standard solution or will people expect rather smart implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour as you're calling `delete` on `tmp` and another thread is consuming it.

One fix would be to create and pass (by value) a `std::shared_ptr` rather than the bare pointer into your worker thread. You can use `release` and `reset` methods in your main loop. The memory will be released by `std::shared_ptr` once the worker thread is done with it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have never used shared_ptr, let me just goole how to use them. It it works I will update here.. :)

Comment: Hey, I am unable to find appropriate example of shared_ptr with threads. Can you please put some light on this.